# Execute R code on server via node

Tags: javascript, r, node.js

I made a website where I can write code into a textfield and I want to send this code to my nodes.js server and call R, which is installed on my server, and make it process the written R code.

What I have trouble with is, how can I start R on my server and input code into it via Javascript?

The security aspects are not relevant for this because it will never go live and will always stay localhost.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an R web framework, you can then use the eval function to run the contents of the text box as code.

Obviously, this is very risky, but you've said you only want this to run locally.

You could use other languages with an exec function to spawn a child process. Write the code to file, compile with exec, then run with the exec function.

In node you could use a child process to achieve this
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

In PHP you could use exec to the same end
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

All of these options carry the same risk.

If you want to safely execute R code on the server, you could implement an RPC mechanism, a simple one would consist of the name of the command and the parameters to be passed. This way, you can effectively whitelist what is allowed to execute, but it does mean you can't excecute arbitrary R code.